# running python scripts present in Dropbox online (not in desktop) in spyder

Tags: python, dropbox

I am unable to install Dropbox Desktop in my Linux system. I have two computers, one at home and another at work. I know I can upload scripts in one and download to the other computer while working from Dropbox. I was curious, is there a way to run the python script directly in spyder from Dropbox online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox can *store* your scripts, but doesn't really have a code execution environment. In theory, you could pull the scripts out of Dropbox using the API and into a cloud ecosystem to run, but at that point it may be easier just to host the scripts directly where you want them to run!

I might be able to offer more specific advice if you can describe the use case a bit.

EDIT:
So it sounds like you're going to be working with the scripts locally and just need a way to upload / download them without having access to the Dropbox app. Does this *need* to be programmatic (API) instead of using the Web UI?
RE:the Dropbox API, using the [files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) and [files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download) endpoints will give you access to your files. You can also use the [files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) endpoint to list the contents of a folder. Keep in mind that once the contents of the folder grow to large to be returned in a single files/list_folder call, you'll need to use [files/list_folder/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue) to get the rest of the contents.

Comment: Hi Taylor, thank you so much for your comment. I want to upload scripts in dropbox in the computer at home and use and edit (when needed) those script at work in another computer on which I am unable to install it. I need to download and upload all the time, so I just wanted to use some API to access the scripts in dropbox online and run it in spyder notebook. Also, want to save the changes I do at work, so I can access them at home. (Possibly stack community wont like my idea but is my naive thought).

Comment: Thanks Taylor for nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think https://github.com was invented exactly for your usecase.

*(Sorry about the irony, seriously, just use github/gitlab/bitbucket instead of Dropbox for code sharing, versioning, etc. Github in specific has free private repos.)*

Comment: Update to my somewhat ironic answer: Google Colab, a very useful service that runs your Jupyter notebooks, does store the files in Google Drive, similar to Dropbox usercase. There is also some diff. My conclusion: Drive/Dropbox are quite valid for storing notebooks.